# Variables do not seem to parsing sql search data in WordPress

Tags: php, sql, wordpress

I have this code:

```
 <?php
     $gregorianMonth = date(n);
     $gregorianDay = date(j);
     $gregorianYear = date(Y);

     $jdDate = gregoriantojd($gregorianMonth,$gregorianDay,$gregorianYear); 

     $hebrewMonthName = jdmonthname($jdDate,4);

     $hebrewDate = jdtojewish($jdDate); 

     list($hebrewMonth, $hebrewDay, $hebrewYear) = split('/',$hebrewDate);
 ?>

 <?php
      $table_name =  "candle_number";
      $data = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT email FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE  `datehebrew` LIKE \"$hebrewDay $hebrewMonth%\" AND `date_pref` = \"hebrew\";");

      $final_output = array();

      foreach( $data as $rs ){

      $final_output[] = $rs->email;

      }

      echo json_encode($final_output);
 ?>
```

And what I am doing with my data is matching the current hebrew day and month with what was put into the database. Users had added spaces so I added the wildcard as well.

This is a PhP operation I am pretty familiar with but for some reason this one is not working. What could I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering how I accomplished it, finally:

```
 <?php
    $gregorianMonth = date('n');
    $gregorianDay = date('j');
    $gregorianYear = date('Y');

    $jdDate = gregoriantojd($gregorianMonth,$gregorianDay,$gregorianYear); 

    $hebrewMonthName = jdmonthname($jdDate,4);

    $hebrewDate = jdtojewish($jdDate); 

    list($hebrewMonth, $hebrewDay, $hebrewYear) = split('/',$hebrewDate);

    $table_name = "candle_number";
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT email FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE date_pref = \"hebrew\" AND datehebrew LIKE \"$hebrewDay $hebrewMonthName 5%\"");

    $final_output = array();

    foreach( $results as $rs ){

    $final_output[] = $rs->email;

    }

    echo json_encode($final_output);

?>
```